# MySQL - Time difference between one row and the current row being inserted

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a MySQL table that looks something like this:

```
id        timestamp                action        timePassed

1         2012-07-10 22:44:00      start         0
2         2012-07-10 22:44:50      pause         50
3         2012-07-10 22:45:30      play          50
4         2012-07-10 22:47:25      pause         205
5         2012-07-10 22:48:05      play          205
```

I don't know how obvious it is but what's happening here is basically on every 'pause' row I am calculating the difference in seconds between the current timestamp and the timestamp of the 'start' row.

The only way I can think of doing this is to INSERT a new 'pause' row into the database so the timestamp is generated...then query the database for the timestamp of that 'pause' row...calculate the difference in seconds between that 'pause' row and the 'start' row using PHP...then UPDATE the 'pause' row with the timePassed result.

My question is whether or not there is a better way to do this (i.e. using timediff or some other MySQL command). The issue is the 'pause' timestamp doesn't exist until I make the INSERT, so I feel like that needs to happen first before I can make any calculation?

Comment: Why are you storing `timePassed` at all? It would seem to me that you don't need to. The interval between any two actions is already stored once just by having each timestamp. By storing the same thing in multiple places, you're subject to update anomalies (e.g. `timePassed` being stored as 30 when the actual interval was 50). I would recommend calculating the interval in a query or perhaps a view.

Comment: And as long as I'm being the normalization police, I guess I'll also recommend that you have a separate `action` table with just one distinct value for each possible action, and then an `action_id` foreign key in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your table is like this and your requirement is like this then you are on track..

However better if you check the second difference between last row and last to last row. This will give you idea for how many second user has PAUSED or Played the TRACK.

```
INSERT INTO table (timestamp, action, timePassed)
    SELECT now(), 'pause', SECOND(timediff(now(), timestamp))
    FROM table
    WHERE ID = (Select Max(ID) from Table)
```

Put action as you like so you can insert time difference between two.

Comment: Swapped SECOND() with TIME_TO_SEC() and it suits my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I can think of doing this is to INSERT a new 'pause' row
>   into the database so the timestamp is generated...then query the
>   database for the timestamp of that 'pause' row...calculate the
>   difference in seconds between that 'pause' row and the 'start' row
>   using PHP...then UPDATE the 'pause' row with the timePassed result.

You can INSERT the already calculated row.

```
INSERT INTO table (timestamp, action, timePassed)
    SELECT now(), 'pause', SECOND(timediff(now(), timestamp))
    FROM table
    WHERE action = 'start'; -- and/or other WHERE clauses.
```

This will introduce a skew in time due to the time needed to retrieve the 'start' row (but with index on action (and maybe timestamp if the row is very large), that time should be negligible).

Comment: Yeah, that was my question. Are an INSERT and an UPDATE both necessary. Or is it possible to do it all in one INSERT with some timediff MySQL command?

Comment: The second one you said :-) -- updated answer. Of course you need one statement, but that statement is double - SELECTS one value and INSERTS the new.

Comment: ...aaaand sorry, my original thought about time difference was wrong in too many ways. Edited again :-(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not storing `timePassed` explicitly at all, since by having each event's timestamp, you already have every interval stored once. If you separately store `timePassed`, you'll be storing the same data in multiple places. To quote E. F. Codd, "If something is true, saying it twice doesn't make it any more true." Also, you're subject to update anomalies when you store the same thing multiple times.

If you want to calculate the interval with a query, this might work.

```
SELECT event.id,
       event.timestamp,
       event.action,
       TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(event.timestamp, start_event.timestamp)) time_passed
  FROM event
  JOIN (SELECT timestamp
          FROM event
         WHERE event.action = 'start') start_event ON 1 = 1
```